# Making NSBordlessWindow key and active when main application window is not active

Tags: osx-mavericks, nswindow, becomefirstresponder, makekeyandordertofront, nsborderlesswindowmask

I have a custom `NSBorderlessWindowMask` window in my application that I show when user taps a certain hot key.
This window has a `NSTextField, that has to become first responder when the window shows up.
This window is not a main window, but it can take focus from the main window.
This what I do to show it and make it key:

```
[self.myCustomWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
```

and then to set the first responder

```
[self.myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Everything works as expected when the application is a frontmost application,
but if it's not, the window appears, but doesn't become key and i have to click it to become active.

I override in my `CustomWindow` class:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {

    return YES;
}
```

What might be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Cocoa Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html), only the frontmost application can have main and key window status:

> When an application is displaying both a main window and a key window,
>   the responder chains of both windows can be involved in an action
>   message. As explained in “Window Layering and Types of Windows”, the
>   main window is the frontmost document or application window. Often
>   main windows also have key status, meaning they are the current focus
>   of user input. But a main window can have a secondary window or panel
>   associated with it, such as the Find panel or a Info window showing
>   details of a selection in the document window. When this secondary
>   window is the focus of user input, then it is the key window.

I don't see any way around this.

EDIT: Also from the [Window Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/ChangingMainKeyWindow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000236):

> Since the key window belongs to the active application, its
>   highlighted title bar has the secondary effect of helping to show
>   which application is currently active. The key window is the most
>   prominently marked window in the active application, making it “key”
>   in a second sense: it’s the main focus of the user’s attention on the
>   screen.

Comment: But I don't need it to become main. I just want it to become key. I just need a focus on the text field, so it becomes the first responder as the window becomes from window

Comment: @NavaCarmon Added another quote from an Apple document.  The key window belongs to the active application.  I don't see how this can be easily changed.

Comment: I tried to add [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES] before making it key and it works.